# Translate UIView by dragging another UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform, uipangesturerecognizer

Please refer to the image below for the following question: The blue and orange circles you see are UIView's. I would like to be able to drag the blue UIView which has a UIPanGestureRecognizer and have the **orange circle translate accordingly and stay the same distance from the blue circle as it does now.** Meaning, if I drag the blue circle down, the orange UIView should stay parallel with the blue circle and translate down as well. If I drag the blue circle to the right, the orange circle should translate to the right as well and **stay the same distance from the blue circle as it does now.**

[image]

So right now the circles are part of the same class that have a UIPanGestureRecognizer on them. Here is the code to drag these views:

```
-(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)p {


UIView *newView = p.view;
if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    self.origC = newView.center;
}
self.delta = [p translationInView:newView.superview];
CGPoint c = self.origC;

c.x +=self.delta.x;
c.y +=self.delta.y;

newView.center = c;

[self.delegate refreshView];
}
```

Within the UIPanGestureRecognizer class, I am able to obtain the translation of the pan gesture in the coordinate system of the specified view with:

`self.delta = [p translationInView:newView.superview];`

I think that this is the delta I need to apply for the translation of the orange circle, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just add `delta` to the other view's center too?

Comment: So both of these views are added as subviews in another UIView (indicated by the purple background). In that superview, within `drawRect:`, I have tried adding that delta to the other view's center as follows: 
`self.fp2.center = CGPointMake(self.fp2.center.x+self.deltaDrag.x, self.fp2.center.y+self.deltaDrag.y);`

This causes the orange view to fly out of the window at first drag of the blue view.

Comment: you add the delta to the original center of the orange view or current   center ? As delta is the total translation over time.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I got it with the answer below.

Comment: @DanielRak you should accept an answer or post you own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it exactly as you are doing it for the directly dragged point.

```
if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    self.origC = newView.center; // your code
    self.origD = otherView.center; // new code
}
CGPoint c = self.origC; // your code
c.x +=self.delta.x; // your code
c.y +=self.delta.y; // your code
newView.center = c; // your code
CGPoint d = self.origD; // new code
d.x +=self.delta.x; // new code
d.y +=self.delta.y; // new code
otherView.center = d; // new code
```

Comment: Matt, thank you! You made a couple of little mistakes but I edited your answer in case other people need it. You've been a big help. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the pasted code works however you want to find "a one line code" way,right ?
I guess what you seeking something like this.

```
orangeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(delta.x,delta.y);
```